# Using CLI commands if npm install not globaly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know if I can navigate to the package folder with cmd and run it's cli commands without installing it globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, you don't need to cd to the directory, you can just do something like this:

`node node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js <parameters>`

You'll just need to work out which folder/script file to run within the package folder.